# cognos list in a table by section how do I stop data break across page

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TRw3.png)Cognos Report 11, I have a list inside of a table. The list is sectioned by two data items. How do I prevent the list to break across the page.
I want it to break the page when it finds the end of the page and the current section.

Invoice

List inside of a Table

Comment: It looks like you have too much data to fit on one page.  What is the expected behavior for that case?  Can you provide a sample of the desired output?

Comment: Are you sure that is fake data and not real data?

Comment: have you tried page sets
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.0.0?topic=pages-page-breaks-page-sets-page-layers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have placed items in your page header and page footer that belong in the section header and section footer.

Here is a report spec that demonstrates this.
You didn't specify which version of Cognos you are using.  You may need to fiddle with the version numbers on the first line of this to make it work in your system.

```
<report xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/15.5/" useStyleVersion="11.6" expressionLocale="en-us">
    <drillBehavior/>
    <layouts>
        <layout>
            <reportPages>
                <pageSet name="Page set1" refQuery="Query1">
                    <detailPages>
                        <page name="Page1" refQuery="Query1">
                            <style>
                                <defaultStyles>
                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="pg"/>
                                </defaultStyles>
                            </style>
                            <pageBody>
                                <style>
                                    <defaultStyles>
                                        <defaultStyle refStyle="pb"/>
                                    </defaultStyles>
                                </style>
                                <contents>
                                    <list showColumnTitles="hide" refQuery="Query1" name="List2">
                                        <listColumns>
                                            <listColumn>
                                                <listColumnTitle>
                                                    <contents/>
                                                </listColumnTitle>
                                                <listColumnBody>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <list horizontalPagination="true" name="List1" refQuery="Query1">
                                                            <noDataHandler>
                                                                <contents>
                                                                    <block>
                                                                        <contents>
                                                                            <textItem>
                                                                                <dataSource>
                                                                                    <staticValue>No Data Available</staticValue>
                                                                                </dataSource>
                                                                            </textItem>
                                                                        </contents>
                                                                        <style>
                                                                            <CSS value="padding:16px;"/>
                                                                        </style>
                                                                    </block>
                                                                </contents>
                                                            </noDataHandler>
                                                            <style>
                                                                <CSS value="border-collapse:collapse"/>
                                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="ls"/>
                                                                </defaultStyles>
                                                            </style>
                                                            <listColumns>
                                                                <listColumn>
                                                                    <listColumnTitle>
                                                                        <style>
                                                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                                            </defaultStyles>
                                                                        </style>
                                                                        <contents>
                                                                            <textItem>
                                                                                <dataSource>
                                                                                    <dataItemLabel refDataItem="City"/>
                                                                                </dataSource>
                                                                            </textItem>
                                                                        </contents>
                                                                    </listColumnTitle>
                                                                    <listColumnBody>
                                                                        <style>
                                                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                                            </defaultStyles>
                                                                        </style>
                                                                        <contents>
                                                                            <textItem>
                                                                                <dataSource>
                                                                                    <dataItemValue refDataItem="City"/>
                                                                                </dataSource>
                                                                            </textItem>
                                                                        </contents>
                                                                    </listColumnBody>
                                                                </listColumn>
                                                                <listColumn>
                                                                    <listColumnTitle>
                                                                        <style>
                                                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                                            </defaultStyles>
                                                                        </style>
                                                                        <contents>
                                                                            <textItem>
                                                                                <dataSource>
                                                                                    <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Product line"/>
                                                                                </dataSource>
                                                                            </textItem>
                                                                        </contents>
                                                                    </listColumnTitle>
                                                                    <listColumnBody>
                                                                        <style>
                                                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                                            </defaultStyles>
                                                                        </style>
                                                                        <contents>
                                                                            <textItem>
                                                                                <dataSource>
                                                                                    <dataItemValue refDataItem="Product line"/>
                                                                                </dataSource>
                                                                            </textItem>
                                                                        </contents>
                                                                    </listColumnBody>
                                                                </listColumn>
                                                                <listColumn>
                                                                    <listColumnTitle>
                                                                        <style>
                                                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                                            </defaultStyles>
                                                                        </style>
                                                                        <contents>
                                                                            <textItem>
                                                                                <dataSource>
                                                                                    <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Last name"/>
                                                                                </dataSource>
                                                                            </textItem>
                                                                        </contents>
                                                                    </listColumnTitle>
                                                                    <listColumnBody>
                                                                        <style>
                                                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                                            </defaultStyles>
                                                                        </style>
                                                                        <contents>
                                                                            <textItem>
                                                                                <dataSource>
                                                                                    <dataItemValue refDataItem="Last name"/>
                                                                                </dataSource>
                                                                            </textItem>
                                                                        </contents>
                                                                    </listColumnBody>
                                                                </listColumn>
                                                                <listColumn>
                                                                    <listColumnTitle>
                                                                        <style>
                                                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                                            </defaultStyles>
                                                                        </style>
                                                                        <contents>
                                                                            <textItem>
                                                                                <dataSource>
                                                                                    <dataItemLabel refDataItem="First name"/>
                                                                                </dataSource>
                                                                            </textItem>
                                                                        </contents>
                                                                    </listColumnTitle>
                                                                    <listColumnBody>
                                                                        <style>
                                                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                                            </defaultStyles>
                                                                        </style>
                                                                        <contents>
                                                                            <textItem>
                                                                                <dataSource>
                                                                                    <dataItemValue refDataItem="First name"/>
                                                                                </dataSource>
                                                                            </textItem>
                                                                        </contents>
                                                                    </listColumnBody>
                                                                </listColumn>
                                                                <listColumn>
                                                                    <listColumnTitle>
                                                                        <style>
                                                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                                            </defaultStyles>
                                                                        </style>
                                                                        <contents>
                                                                            <textItem>
                                                                                <dataSource>
                                                                                    <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Revenue"/>
                                                                                </dataSource>
                                                                            </textItem>
                                                                        </contents>
                                                                    </listColumnTitle>
                                                                    <listColumnBody>
                                                                        <style>
                                                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="lm"/>
                                                                            </defaultStyles>
                                                                        </style>
                                                                        <contents>
                                                                            <textItem>
                                                                                <dataSource>
                                                                                    <dataItemValue refDataItem="Revenue"/>
                                                                                </dataSource>
                                                                            </textItem>
                                                                        </contents>
                                                                    </listColumnBody>
                                                                </listColumn>
                                                            </listColumns>
                                                            <sortList>
                                                                <sortItem refDataItem="City"/>
                                                                <sortItem refDataItem="Product line"/>
                                                                <sortItem refDataItem="Last name"/>
                                                                <sortItem refDataItem="First name"/>
                                                            </sortList>
                                                        </list>
                                                    </contents>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="sb"/>
                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                    </style>
                                                </listColumnBody>
                                            </listColumn>
                                        </listColumns>
                                        <style>
                                            <CSS value="border-collapse:collapse; width:100%"/>
                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="sc"/>
                                            </defaultStyles>
                                        </style>
                                        <listGroups>
                                            <listGroup refDataItem="Country">
                                                <listHeader>
                                                    <listRows>
                                                        <listRow>
                                                            <rowCells>
                                                                <rowCell>
                                                                    <contents>
                                                                        <textItem>
                                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                                <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                                            </dataSource>
                                                                        </textItem>
                                                                        <textItem>
                                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                                <staticValue>: </staticValue>
                                                                            </dataSource>
                                                                        </textItem>
                                                                        <textItem>
                                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                                            </dataSource>
                                                                        </textItem>
                                                                        <textItem>
                                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                                <staticValue> header</staticValue>
                                                                            </dataSource>
                                                                        </textItem>
                                                                    </contents>
                                                                    <style>
                                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="sh"/>
                                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                                    </style>
                                                                </rowCell>
                                                            </rowCells>
                                                        </listRow>
                                                    </listRows>
                                                </listHeader>
                                                <listFooter>
                                                    <listRows>
                                                        <listRow>
                                                            <rowCells>
                                                                <rowCell>
                                                                    <contents>
                                                                        <textItem>
                                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                                <dataItemValue refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                                            </dataSource>
                                                                        </textItem>
                                                                        <textItem>
                                                                            <dataSource>
                                                                                <staticValue> footer</staticValue>
                                                                            </dataSource>
                                                                        </textItem>
                                                                    </contents>
                                                                    <style>
                                                                        <defaultStyles>
                                                                            <defaultStyle refStyle="of"/>
                                                                        </defaultStyles>
                                                                    </style>
                                                                </rowCell>
                                                            </rowCells>
                                                        </listRow>
                                                    </listRows>
                                                </listFooter>
                                                <sortList>
                                                    <sortItem refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                </sortList>
                                            </listGroup>
                                        </listGroups>
                                        <sectionsFrame sectionedEdge="columns" refFrame="List1"/>
                                        <masterDetailLinks>
                                            <masterDetailLink>
                                                <masterContext>
                                                    <dataItemContext refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                </masterContext>
                                                <detailContext>
                                                    <dataItemContext refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                </detailContext>
                                            </masterDetailLink>
                                        </masterDetailLinks>
                                    </list>
                                </contents>
                            </pageBody>
                            <pageHeader>
                                <contents>
                                    <textItem>
                                        <dataSource>
                                            <staticValue>page header</staticValue>
                                        </dataSource>
                                    </textItem>
                                </contents>
                            </pageHeader>
                            <pageFooter>
                                <contents>
                                    <textItem>
                                        <dataSource>
                                            <staticValue>page footer</staticValue>
                                        </dataSource>
                                    </textItem>
                                </contents>
                            </pageFooter>
                            <masterDetailLinks>
                                <masterDetailLink>
                                    <masterContext>
                                        <dataItemContext refDataItem="Country"/>
                                    </masterContext>
                                    <detailContext>
                                        <dataItemContext refDataItem="Country"/>
                                    </detailContext>
                                </masterDetailLink>
                            </masterDetailLinks>
                            <XMLAttributes>
                                <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_legacyDrillDown" value="0"/>
                            </XMLAttributes>
                        </page>
                    </detailPages>
                    <pageGroups>
                        <pageGroup refDataItem="Country">
                            <sortList>
                                <sortItem refDataItem="Country"/>
                            </sortList>
                        </pageGroup>
                    </pageGroups>
                </pageSet>
            </reportPages>
        </layout>
    </layouts>
    <XMLAttributes>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_CreateExtendedDataItems" value="true"/>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="listSeparator" value=","/>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="decimalSeparator" value="."/>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_modelModificationTime" value="2015-11-25T21:38:24.820Z"/>
    </XMLAttributes>
    <queries>
        <query name="Query1">
            <source>
                <model/>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem aggregate="total" name="Revenue">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales].[Revenue]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="2"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="2"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Country">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Branch].[Country]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="City">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Branch].[City]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Last name">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales staff].[Last name]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="First name">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales staff].[First name]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Product line">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Products].[Product line]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
        </query>
    </queries>
    <modelPath>/content/folder[@name=&apos;Samples&apos;]/folder[@name=&apos;Models&apos;]/package[@name=&apos;GO sales (query)&apos;]/model[@name=&apos;model&apos;]</modelPath>
</report>
```

Comment: I am using Cognos 11.1.7

Comment: I added an image of the PDF. I have put the list inside of a Table. I disabled the Table Allow Contents to break across the page. The contents still break across the page. Is there a render variable I can use with the row number? The customer does not want page set where each project is on it's own page.